# How to detect wither the user has clicked OK or CANCEL on Intent.ACTION_DELETE?

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation

I'm trying to make an uninstaller app and this is the part that I use to uninstall an app:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", app.getPackageName(), null);
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

When the user clicks the uninstall button, a confirmation popup dialog appear. Is there a way to check if the user has clicked OK or CANCEL in the dialog box ?

Answer (score 5):

Never mind guys, I finally found the solution: instead of ACTION_DELETE, I used ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE (minimum API 14) and this is the final code:

```
private void uninstallApps(List<AppModel> apps) {
    for (AppModel app : apps) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", app.getPackageName(), null);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, uri);
        // store result
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // get result
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: OK");
    }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: CANCEL");
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, as [`ACTION_DELETE` is not documented to return anything](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DELETE).

When your activity returns to the foreground, though, you could use `PackageManager` and see if the app is still there.

Answer (score 1):

in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
```

in onCreate

```
val uri = Uri.parse("package:${app.packageName}")
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true)

val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    when(result.resultCode) {
        Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {}
        Activity.RESULT_OK -> {}
        else -> {}//we get android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
    }
}
```

in setOnClickListener

```
startForResult.launch(intent)
```

Note, if the user quickly click on your "delete application" button several times, which calls `setOnClickListener`, the several windows will start offering "delete the application?", you should protect yourself from this